# How can i fix Page not found 404 in django?

Tags: django

Hi ive been coding my first website and then try running the product page I get this error

```
*Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/products
Using the URLconf defined in myshop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
The current path, products, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.*
```

how can I solve this? Here is my code...

my views page code

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')


def new(request):
    return HttpResponse('New Products')
```

`productsurls code`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('new', views.new)
]
```

`myshopurls`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = {
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('products/', include('products.urls'))
}
```

Comment: Include the app in your settings.py file under INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]....how do i do that...the app is called myshop

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, you are facing this problem because you have not include your app "products" in the "settings.py" file.

-> After checking your code I can conclude that"myshop" is your project and "products" is your app.

So, you will have to go in settings.py file under which you will find a list "INSTALLED_APPS".

Inside INSTALLED_APPS -> You will have to include your app.

Go to "apps.py" file of the "products" app and copy the name of the "config" class.

After that in your settings.py file, you will have to write 'products.apps.(paste the name of config class)'.

Most probably name of your config class will be "ProductsConfig" -> So, you will have to write **'products.apps.ProductsConfig',**

Hope it will work !

Comment: Thank you very much for your response....  INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products.apps.ProductConfig',
]....still not working

Comment: Please go to the apps.py file of products app and check, what is the name of the class there, is it "ProductConfig" or "ProductsConfig"?

Comment: "apps.py"from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProductsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'products'   "settings"  INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products.apps.ProductsConfig',
]

Comment: Is it working now? After putting  'products.apps.ProductsConfig', in  INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: If you face the error again...please post the error in question (screenshot) that is coming when DEBUG = true.

Comment: it isnt working but ill post the screeenshot

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the app under INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py file.

So your settings.py file should read like so

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Built In Apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # User Defined Apps
    'product.apps.ProductConfig',
]
```

---

Tip - If you are confused as to how to include the name under installed Apps. It should be like so

`<myapp>.apps.<name_of_class_in_myapp/apps.py_file>`

Basically navigate to your app folder -> `apps.py` file and check the name of the class. It will be like so

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProductConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'product'
```

You want the name of this class. `ProductConfig`.

---

Note - Local apps should always be added at the bottom because Django executes the
INSTALLED_APPS setting from top to bottom. We want the core Django apps to be available before our app.

The reason for listing the app like

`'product.apps.ProductConfig',`

is because it is best practice and helps if in future if you decide to use [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/).

Comment: thank you so much for your help...still trying but not working.....INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products.apps.ProductConfig',
]

Comment: Refer this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a48xeeo5Vnk&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=2